# What is the logical reasoning that allows us to work backwards with implications? If $C \implies D$ and $E \implies C$, then $E \implies D$

Tags: logic

I understand that we can work forwards using logical implications:

If $A \implies B$ and $B \implies C $, then $A \implies C$.

However, I am unsure of the reasoning that allows us to work backwards.

1. For instance, If $C \implies D$ and $E \implies C$, then $E
       \implies D$. Whereas working sequentially forwards with
   implications seems to make logical sense, I am not sure of the
   reasoning that makes it logical to work in a 'discontinuous'
   fashion, as show in the preceding example.
2. I am also wondering if, in the preceding example, we could also say
   that $D \implies E$?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to explain the reasoning behind this concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this even correct? We cannot derive $E\Rightarrow C$ using $E\Rightarrow D$ and $C\Rightarrow D$.

Comment: @Levent You're correct. I made a typing error and have fixed it. I apologise!

Comment: $E\Rightarrow C$ and $C\Rightarrow D$ is the same thing as $C\Rightarrow D$ and $E\Rightarrow C$. You say that you understand the forwards using logical implications, this is the same thing.

Comment: 2) No, you can't. For instance, if this evening I decided to sacrifice a human being to the Sun God while wearing a lioncloth and some ostrich feathers, tomorrow the sun will rise. And, if tomorrow the sun rises, the night won't last forever. On the other hand, the fact that tonight is not going to last forever is not a proof that I murdered a person (in fact, I did not).

Comment: @Levent But notice that we did not work forwards to $D \implies E$: that's what I meant by sequential.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That makes sense. Thank you. What about the reasoning behind (1)?

Comment: You're saying that you understand "If $A\implies B$ and $B\implies C$ than $A\implies C$" but you don't understand "if $B\implies C$ and $A\implies B$ then $A\implies C$"? What is the difference you see between "$A\implies B$ and $B\implies C$" and "$B\implies C$ and $A\implies B$"?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In logic we have "And" as a product. And product is commutative.

If $C \implies D$ and $E \implies C$ is same as $E \implies C$ and $C \implies D$ then you can say $E \implies D$.

Comment: The "and" here is a conjunction in the *metalanguage*, not in the syntax of propositional logic.

Answer (score 1):

Both situations mentioned in the question arise from the fact that implication is *transitive*: If $p_1 \Rightarrow p_2$ and $p_2 \Rightarrow p_3$, then $p_1 \Rightarrow p_3$.

Can we conclude that if $p_1 \Rightarrow p_2$ and $p_2 \Rightarrow p_3$, then also $p_3 \rightarrow p_1$? No. A simple counterexample is the case where $p_1$ is false, $p_2$ is false and $p_3$ is true.